# Bloons Tower Defense 5 Upgrade Paths

Tags: bloons-td-5

If you upgrade both paths then buy the third of one do you loose all the upgrades on the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, getting the third upgrade of one path just locks you out of the third (and fourth) upgrade of the other path *for that one tower*.